# How to convert mouse position to line number?

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I'm trying to convert the position of the mouse (mouseEvent->pos()) to the line number.

In simple words, like setting a breakpoint in visual c++ by clicking on the left side. So I want to get the line number where the mouse was clicked and doSomething() at that line.

I'm not sure if I was able to explain it clearly, but let know if you can't I need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I couldn't explain it well, but I found the solution. Thanks for trying though.

Here's the solution,

```
    bool ViewScriptEditor::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
    {
        bool bReturn = false;
        do
        {
            if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
            {       
                QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*> (event);
                QPointF swipe_startPoint = mouseEvent->pos();        
                QTextDocument *pDoc = document();
                if (!pDoc)
                    break;

                QTextBlock block = pDoc->findBlock((int)swipe_startPoint.ry());

                int lines = block.blockNumber();// +1;

                emit this->signalUpdateYourFunction(lines);

                //repaint();

            }
        } while (false);

        return bReturn;
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong.QTextBlock QTextDocument::findBlock(int pos) accepts the character position, not the y position of the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question.

Maybe you could try to reimplement mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *Event) and do something like that :

```
QRect   m_WidgetRect = UrWidget.rect();

X = Event->x();
Y = Event->y();

if (X >= m_WidgetRect.x() && X <= m_WidgetRect.x() + m_WidgetRect.width()) {
    if (Y >= m_WidgetRect.y() && Y <= m_WidgetRect.y() m_WidgetRect.height(){
        Do something;
    }
}
```